# Views are getting resized to 1000X1000 in Storyboard or Xib - Xcode8

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, xib, xcode8

Views that are aligned using Autolayout are getting collapsed with Xcode8. If we close and reopen the storyboard or xib file, some of the views are automatically resized to 1000X1000. Is it a bug?

How can we get over it? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you are referring to the warning xcode gives with the views' frames, let the interface builder fix it for you by using 'Update Frame' Fix misplacement. I encounter same issue as well

Comment: Updating frame by Autolayout error entirely collapses the view and I have to redesign it at times. This is really eating my time and leads to lot of rework

Comment: Please describe the issue and your setup more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your Storyboard in Xcode version that is below 8.x, maybe 7.3.x . Make sure you do not have any ambiguous constraint warnings and fix them if any. Then move on to Xcode 8 and open up your storyboard and click on **Update frames**. It should work.

If there are any ambiguous/improper constraints at the time of updating frames, the auto layout setup would collapse. You need to spend some time to update the auto layout constraints when migrating from Xcode 7.x to 8.